# Calculating objects without generating too much garbage

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection

At the moment I'm developing a game for Android. For this all my objects have a `Vec3` position. This is an excerpt from the class:

```
public class Vec3 {
    public float x, y, z;

    public Vec3(float x, float y, float z) {
        this.x = x; this.y = y; this.z = z;
    }

    public Vec3 add(Vec3 v) {
        return new Vec3(this.x + v.x, this.y - v.y, this.z + v.z);
    }

    public Vec3 sub(Vec3 v) {
        return new Vec3(this.x - v.x, this.y - v.y, this.z - v.z);
    }
}
```

Now let's say I want to run this code where `a`, `b` and `c` are vectors from the `Vec3` class:

```
a.add(b).sub(c);
```

If I run this code with many different vectors it comes to lags in my game because sometimes when the vectors are not needed anymore the garbage collector will remove them all at the same time. I thought that I can solve the problem with a `variable pool` but here is the problem.. I do not exactly know when the vector is not used anymore in my game so I do not know where I have to check the vector in.

Another problem is that I generate a lot of vector objects at the add and sub method. I want to calculate the vectors without to change them itself thats why I return a new `Vec3` every time. Let's say I run this code:

```
a.add(b).add(b).add(b).add(b).add(b).sub(c);
```

With that I generate six new vector objects but if you think about that I only need one to calculate the vectors and to store the result without to change the original vectors. This is also a problem which I can't solve with a `variable pool`.

Do you have any ideas how I can solve this problems in an efficient way?

Comment: Just checking: You *have* determined, with actual performance data, that your problems are really due to garbage collection overhead, and that these objects constitute a significant portion of that overhead, right? I would expect those temporaries to be collected very quickly and cheaply, very rarely lasting past a single generation.

Comment: Yes I'm sure that these problems come from the garbage collection overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You can write in-place `add` and `sub` methods:

```
public Vec3 addInPlace(Vec3 v) {
    x += v.x;
    y += v.y;
    z += v.z;
    return this;
}

// and similarly for subInPlace
```

and then use those to avoid making extra temporaries:

```
temp = a.add(b);
temp.addInPlace(b).addInPlace(b).addInPlace(b).addInPlace(b).subInPlace(c);
```

You have to manage the object reuse explicitly, and you lose the immutability of `Vec3` objects. Both of those things suck.

Answer (score 0):

In your more complicated example

```
a.add(b).add(b).add(b).add(b).add(b).sub(c);
```

you can eliminate most garbage by using a more powerful operation

```
a.mulAdd(4, b, -1, c);
```

I would be afraid of multiplication timing, but not much. You could also write specialized operations like

```
a.addFourSubOne(b, c);
```

which sounds rather idiotic as you can never implement all operations you can *possibly* use. OTOH you can easily implement all operations ypu *really* use.

---

I'd probably recommend to use mutable objects. You can provide both mutating and copying operations for them, called something like `add`/`addInPlace` or `plus`/`add`. You could also implement both mutable and immutable versions (this gets boring soon, but you can manage it by not implementing anything you don't actually need).